# Keeping the value salected in the drop-down list after the search

Tags: python, django

I have got a filter on my page, that filters my items by the category. You can choose the category from a drop-down list and then press search and the filtered content is displayed. The only problem is that, the drop-down list resets and doesn't show the category, that the current items are filtered by. Anyone knows how to solve this?

views.py

```
def HomeView(request):
  item_list = Item.objects.all()
  item_list = item_list.annotate(
      current_price=Coalesce('discount_price', 'price'))

  category_list = Category.objects.all()
  query = request.GET.get('q')

  if query:
      item_list = item_list.filter(title__icontains=query)

  cat = request.GET.get('cat')
  if cat:
      item_list = item_list.filter(category__pk=cat)

  price_from = request.GET.get('price_from')
  price_to = request.GET.get('price_to')

  if price_from:
      item_list = item_list.filter(current_price__gte=price_from)

  if price_to:
      item_list = item_list.filter(current_price__lte=price_to)

  paginator = Paginator(item_list, 10)

  page = request.GET.get('page')

  try:
      items = paginator.page(page)
  except PageNotAnInteger:
      items = paginator.page(1)
  except EmptyPage:
      items = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

  context = {
      'items': items,
      'category': category_list
  }
  return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

html:

```
        <form method="GET" action=".">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="category">Category</label>
            <select id="cat" class="form-control" name="cat">
                <option value="" selected>Choose...</option>
                <option value="" href="/home">All</option>
                {% for cat in category %}
                <option value="{{ cat.pk }}">
                    {{ cat }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
       </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In template you can add `selected` attribute to value from `request.GET.cat`:

```
<option value="" {% if not request.GET.cat %} selected {% endif %}>Choose...</option>
{% for cat in category %}
   <option value="{{ cat.pk }}" {% if request.GET.cat == cat.pk|slugify %} selected {% endif %}>
      {{ cat }}
   </option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Doesnt work, after the search it comes back to "Choose.."

Comment: @Menor oh, you also need to remove selected from choose item. CHeck updated answer.

Comment: Unfortunetly still the same outcome, I even deleted `selected` from the option "Choose..", but nothing has changed

Comment: @Menor oops, you need to convert pk to string. You can use `slugify` filter for this. Check updates again:)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the value of your dropdown to what the user selects. 
For example: If I selected 'Cats' then update your dropdown's default value to 'Cats'.

Basically just keep updating the default value of your dropdown and then check against that.

Hope that helps! :)